# Can I see if finished SLURM job were on dependency?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm, sacct

Is there a way to find out if jobs that I already ran with SLURM workload manager where on a dependency ?

The sacct command has an option "pending" which should show if a job was on hold, but in my case it just prints out all jobs:

`sacct -M cm2 --state PENDING -S2020-01-01T11:20:00 -E2021-01-01T11:20:00 --format="JobName, TimeLimit, State, Partition"`

cm2 in the above command is the cluster I am working on, And I want do show all "pending" jobs from 01.01.2020 to 01.01.2021.

Am I not using the command correctly or is there a better way to directly see if jobs were on dependency?

Answer (score 1):

sacct -M cm2 --state PENDING -S2020-01-01T11:20:00 -E2021-01-01T11:20:00 --format="JobName, TimeLimit, State, Partition, Reason"

Adding Reason will report out as "Dependency"

Just did research on this... I am sure you figured this out by now.